# Abstracting Automated Testing Code Into Python Objects

Tags: python, automated-tests, appium

I currently am doing some automated testing via Appium and python for testing an Android application. I'd like to abstract away some of the details so the tests read easier.

Right now I have just have an entire class doing the testing. For example, I'd like to turn this:

```
# authentication

self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
username = self.driver.find_element_by_name('username')
password = self.driver.find_element_by_name('pw')
username.send_keys('some username')
password.send_keys('some password')
login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_name('Login')
login_button.click()
```

Into something like this:

```
Authentication.login(self.driver, 'largedata_lgabriel@hmbnet.com', 'R3DruM24')
```

Where our Authentication class might look like this:

```
class Authentication:

    def login(driver, username, password):
        input_username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
        input_password = driver.find_element_by_name('pw')
        input_username.send_keys(username)
        input_password.send_keys(password)
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_name('Login')
        login_button.click()
```

This would require creating an 'Authentication' class, but I'm unsure how to import these methods into my main testing class, and how to share the web driver object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I structure this kind of thing. I also use unittest.TestCase which I want to highly recommend for any python automation; it'll allow you to lean on `setUpClass`, `tearDownClass` (one-time for all the derivative tests), and `setUp`, `tearDown` (before each test function) to do a lot of the set up and tear down stuff you need to do.

For my iOS-specific Appium tests:

Base file: `ios_base.py`

```
class iOSBase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        # Set up logging if you want it
        # Set up the XCode and iOS Simulator details you need if you're doing iOS
        # Set up Appium

    def setUp(self):
        # Per test, I like to log the start of each test
        self.log.info("--- {0} ---".format(self._testMethodName))

    # etc. on setUp / tearDown stuff, whatever you need

    # Helpful function like you have in mind
    def login(self, username, password):
        # You'll get self.driver for free by using setUpClass, yea!
```

Test file(s): `test_login.py`

```
from ios_base import iOSBase

class iOSLoginTests(iOSBase):
    # Add any additional login-specific setUp you might want here, see also super()

    def test_valid_login(self):
        self.login(good_username, good_password)

    def test_login_invalid_username(self):
        self.login(bad_username, good_password)

    # etc.
```